# jQuery select all element starting with "o" and followed by number

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, each, jquery-events, mouseenter

I would like to add event on some div. The object is when a user put his mouse on a div, do something and when his mouse exit my div do some other thing. I would like to add that event on each div with begin with "0" followed by an number directly. But the problem is I can't access to jQuery official doc and I don't find the right way to do that with Google.
I think that:

```
$('div[id^="o"]')
```

it work but I would like to be sure that it select only the right div and not the other who start with o and aren't followed directly by a number.

To do my event is possible to something like that?

```
$(the right selector).each(function whenMouseEnter(element,id), function whenMouseExit(element,id));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because jQuery lacks a regular-expression function for it's selectors, you'll need to use `filter()` to explicitly test each found element's `id`:

```
$('div[id^="o"]').filter(function () {
    return (/^o\d/).test(this.id);
}).hover(function () {
    // mouse over
}, function () {
    // mouse leave
});
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
  - [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test);
- jQuery:

  - [`filter()`](http://api.jQuery.com/filter/).
  - [`hover()`](http://api.jQuery.com/hover/).

Comment: can I add 2 variables element and id in functions to refer the actual div ?

Comment: Yes, if you want to; what is that you're trying to do?

Comment: I have to show/hide a child element when mouse is over but with your help it's done like I wanted. Thank you one more time